# Azure Comos - order by empty array element

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a data set that has an array property. Example when I `select * from c`:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "props": []
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "props": ["a"]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "props": ["b"]
  }
]
```

I want to run this query to order by the props column:

`select * from c order by c.props`

BUT it returns 0 records because the first array item is empty (if I drop the order by it works fine and returns the three records).  I can do this to attempt to work around it:

`select c.* as item, props = [] ? '' : props[0] as orderCol from c`

Returns all three items (has no order by) but when I try to apply the order by like this:

`select c.* as item, props = [] ? '' : props[0] as orderCol from c order by c.orderCol`

It returns 0 records.  What am I doing wrong?  (I dont want a where clause to filter the empty props records).  Basically, I can't order by my custom selected field **"orderCol"** when I want to.

NOTE:  using `order by c.id` works fine!

Thanks for any pointers in advance!

Comment: Does the array property only ever have a single item? Strange why an order by would cause 0 results in general, seems broken, although sorting by an array property isn't something I'd say is common or expected given there could be multiple items.

Comment: Want to default sort by first array item really - just doesn't seem to be working at all

Comment: presumably you get an error though and not just zero results?

Comment: Get an error when trying to use the custom field yea

Comment: Not sure how ordering would work with an array, since arrays can contain a variable number of items - that doesn't really make sense. As for missing items: currently indexes only include documents that contain the property in question; see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071480/272109), related to this.

Comment: I was able to work around the empty array fine I just couldnt use the custom property in my sort - has anyone got this going?

Answer (score 1):

Tested your scenario and get the same result.It seems that order by could be mapped to a document path and can't contain not-defined column. I suggest you using below sql:

```
select c.id,IS_DEFINED(c.props[0]) ? c.props[0]:"" as propsVal from c
```

Output:

[image]

Then sort the results by coding,such as [Array.Sort()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8) method in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for trying, its looking like it isn't possible.

Comment: @RobMcCabe Yes,i think so. Maybe you could submit feedback to cosmos db team since this is a common feature i think.